# Sacle up Java web application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat8

This might sound a bit trivial but I am really not able to scale up the JAVA Web Application.

It's basically a API which has to be called each second for , let's say 1,000,000 times.

Basically what happens in the program is that I read a CSV file and then for each user's given pattern of data, I match them and do some sort of calculation on it. **It's most calculations.**

I tried my best and brough the execution time of it to ~120ms and I guess that's pretty good. Now am trying it on my local machine and it's fine. Am working on tomcat8.

So now coming to Web Application,in the main servlet there are `init` , `doPost` and other functions in the servlet.

Am reading the CSV file once in runit function and storing it in an ArrayList and for subsequent doPost requests, am passing that that ArrayList and the user input to one of my class for calculations.

Since runit is executed only once, am getting a peak in time since it's reading the CSV file once and then for following post request's it's getting executed within ~120ms.

**Now the main part,** I tried calling it multiple time using POSTMAN to see what happens when there are multiple requests simultaneously. The result over there was good i.e when tried for 10 requests, it was working as intended.

This is the configuration of my ECLIPSE

```
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx512m
```

So now I deployed my application on AWS Elastic BeanStalk on instance c4.xlarge whose specifications are :

```
           vCPU ECU Memory (GiB)    
c4.xlarge   4   16  7.5
```

Now I am using [loader.io](http://loader.io/) to do the load testing of it and I was hoping to see nothing unexpected.

But after I ran the following test, the program got error-ed out and as seen in the log, I got out of memory exception.
[image: Test Configuration]
[image: Error Report]

So I changed the default configuration to this,

[image]

but still my tests are failing, although am not getting any out of memory exception now.

Can anyone please tell me how do I scale up my application to handle so many hits per second.

I didn't find any setting with which I can fix the max number of connections per second.

Comment: On the contrary, there's nothing trivial about this. Do you expect that there's some setting you can click to make your application scale vertically just like that? There's a heap of work to do to analyze your program, find out hotspots and optimize things.

Comment: Scaling is never trivial....

Comment: Talking about analyzing, what should be minimized? The CPU usage or the memory consumption or what?

Comment: @driftking9987 How about you go to Google, find some interesting articles to read and try again when you have a better idea what you are doing?